# Need to change rows to columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I have a spreadsheet where 5 locker combos for each locker were entered but we did them in a list going down the rows.  Now they want the five to go across in columns.  Is there a way to change these without copying and pasting each one.

Comment: Could you show some example data?  Sounds like you want Paste Special -->Transpose.

Comment: See here for something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272074/transpose-excel-column-to-rows.  Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378863/transposing-2-cell-rows-into-2-cell-columns-quickly/38379069#38379069  Modifying one of those techniques will work for you.

Comment: I added a pic of my sheet the top is what they want and the bottom is what I have now

Comment: Unfortunately I am not good with formulas and could not figure out how to modify the one you sent me.

Comment: It worked great!  Thank you so much.  Sorry for being so needy but I am slowly learning!!

Comment: If my answer below worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 1):

So a quick formula,  This is assuming your data starts in column A, if not adjust your columns accordingly:

```
=IF($A1<>"",INDEX($C:$C,ROW()+COLUMN(A:A)),"")
```

Adjust your columns accordingly on the $A1 and $C:$C.  Leave the COLUMN(A:A) alone as we are using it as a counter and not an actual reference to Column A.

This would go in the cell right next to the first combination, and will return the second combination.  Then copy over three more column and down the entire length of the dataset.

[image]

Then copy and paste just the values on the whole sheet.  Then simple sort on column A, which will bring all the correct rows to the top.  Then delete all the rows beneath.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel's transpose feature to convert data in columns to rows (and vice-versa):

1. Copy the data to be transposed
2. Right-click a cell to paste the data TO
3. On the **Paste Special...** fly-out menu choose Transpose:

   [image]